# Move item from one 2D list cell to another specific cell in the same list

Tags: python, arrays

So, say that I have a 2D list with these items:

```py
foo = [[1,2,3][4,5,6]]
```

and I want to move `foo[1][0]` to `foo[0][1]` to make this output:

```py
foo = [[1,4,2,3][5,6]]
```

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [insert](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_insert.htm) to insert an item into an array into a certain index
- Use [pop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_pop.asp) to remove and return an item from a list at a certain index

## Combine both

```
foo = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
foo[0].insert(1, foo[1].pop(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this

```
foo[0].insert(1,foo[1].pop(0))
```